# Share PHP sessions in cloud file system

Tags: php

I know that putting PHP sessions in a common DB is a good solution, but let's say I have to support apps using standards sessions saved in files. It is possible to share PHP session by a pool of n servers using something like GlusterFS? Is there any possibility of corruption of the session files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just ensure your platform supports entries locking (files — in case of GlusterFS), or at least — atomical write operations: this will ensure your session files are not corrupted.

In fact, you'd better use Memcached/Redis/... any other mem-storage.

Comment: That depends on how heavily you make use of sessions.  If you only really write to them when a user logs in/out, you can safely skip over the locking entirely.

Comment: I need something transparent. Is it possible to use memcache configured by default. Think about a hosting environment.

Comment: Actually I did not it was possible to configure session storage using memcache. It can be configured in php.ini

Comment: Even if you had no option for memcached — you could implement it using <a href="http://ru.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php">session_set_save_handler()</a>